# Redirect addon domain to webapge htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Not quite sure if this is possible. So I have `domain2.com` and it maps to `domain.com`.

On the site I have a page called `/domain-2-landing`

When I hit `domain2.com` I want that to redirect to `domain2.com/domain-2-landing` or even better yet mask `domain.com` and serve the content of `/domain-2-landing`

Is this possible via `.htaccess`?

Comment: "a page called `/domain-2-landing`" - how is the URL `/domain-2-landing` being _routed_? (This doesn't look like it maps directly to a file?)

Comment: @MrWhite It's mapped via the WP plugin MU Domain Mapping and turning off the primary domain setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, since you write about two separate things. Here are two approaches that hopefully will point you into the right direction:

To redirect any request to "domain2.com" to that "landing page" this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain-2-landing$
RewriteRule ^ /domain-2-landing [R=301]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

To deliver the content of that page as a response to requests to "domain.com" there are two diffferent situations:

If the domains are served from separate http servers you can use the proxy feature integrated into the rewriting module *if* the proxy module is installed:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://domain2.com/domain-2-landing [P,END]
```

If both domains are served from a single http server you can do something similar as above, *if* both hosts share the same `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^ /domain-2-landing [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

These rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry only getting back to this now. I can't get it to work yet but I'm sure it's something on my end.

Comment: So I'm using:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain\.com.au$
RewriteRule ^ /home-cclc [END]

When I hit the URL it says: The requested URL /home-cclc was not found on this server.

Comment: You write "When I hit the URL"... when you request _what_ URL?

Comment: And where does that "sub" suddenly come from? You only mentioned "domain" and "domain2".

Comment: Could it be that both host names are not served by the same http server?

Comment: When I request sub.domain.com. Requirement changed and now need to use a subdomain on domain2.com

Comment: "The requested URL /home-cclc was not found" indicates that the server you implemented the internal rewrite in does not have such a resource. Neither in its physical file system nor by any other means of rewriting. Why is nothing we can help with, we do not have knowledge about the content of your service. Let me ask this way 'round: _why_ do you think ` /home-cclc` is a valid resource on your system?

Comment: Because it exists if I visit sub.domain2.com/home-cclc

Comment: Then those are two separate http servers.

Comment: Or you have an issue with character encoding. Make sure you test with that resource copied from the error message into the URL bar and make sure you are using an anonymous tab to to run into caching issues.